# C#: when exporting to text file, bullets are messed up

Tags: c#, file

I have a question- when I `export` my data to text, my text file is not created properly- bullets are messed up.
I have tried to use actual bullet or byte bullet; does not work!

Could you advise on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void createFile()
{
    String Body;
    String TAB = "\t";
    String RETURN = "\r\n";

    Byte[] buffer = new byte[] { (byte)149 };
    string bullet = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buffer);

    Body = TAB + bullet + TAB + "TEXT1" + RETURN;
    Body = Body + "•" + TAB + "TEXT2" + RETURN;
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\fname.txt");
    file.WriteLine(Body);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: How are you *reading* the file? You're writing it out in UTF-8 - is whatever's reading it using UTF-8?

Comment: Please define "messed up" and "does not work"

Comment: @TomBass: Notepad works fine for me...

Comment: @JonSkeet - So it does... my mistake

Comment: he's not reading a file he's creating a file. my answer works for some reason this guy refuses to use the Unicode representation of a "*" Bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I needed to specify different encoding:

```
        String correctString ="•";
        System.IO.StreamWriter ansiWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
        ansiWriter.WriteLine(correctString);
        ansiWriter.Close();
```

Comment: just declare a const string const string correctString = "\u2022";

Comment: try looking at this link as well where you can utilize the Convert.To method http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/docs/ASCIICodes.aspx

Comment: here is another link you can utilize as well http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and it adds a bullet correctly in a text file

```
    String correctString = "\u2022"; 
    System.IO.StreamWriter ansiWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\projects\file.txt", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)); 
    ansiWriter.WriteLine(correctString); 
    ansiWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 2 is the fix.

```
Body = TAB + bullet + TAB + "TEXT1" + RETURN;
Body += TAB + "•" + TAB + "TEXT2" + RETURN;
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\fname.txt");
file.WriteLine(Body);
file.Close();
```

Comment: This is just a syntactical change, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I need new glasses. I'm not sure though if that was the problem, but so far, only Andrew knows.

Comment: "â€¢" - this is what I am getting when I append the "•" symbol to the file

Comment: I am not sure why you are passing two different things in the first body you are assigning Body = Tab + bullet + Tab .... in the example I sent you should use the "\u2022" there is no need to hard code the bullet I tried it and it works for me.. declare a const bullet, assing it's value to "\u2022" and instead of using method overloading append your values into a StringBuiler it's much cleaner in my opinion "Look up mutable vs immutable" strings

Comment: also the text that you pasted does not appear to be a full code block or within a method, paste all the necessary code here, trust me .. your code is not copyright material so we are trying to help you out here.. put the method name and all the stuff variables that you declare it's hard to tell if Body is a Type or a variable with the code you pasted.. thanks

Comment: String correctString = "\u2022"; 
            System.IO.StreamWriter ansiWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\projects\file.txt", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)); 
            ansiWriter.WriteLine(correctString); 
            ansiWriter.Close();             
works you should not use the hard coded value of the bullet use the unicode value

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.Text.Encoding Encoder = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default;
 Byte[] buffer = new byte[]{(byte)149};
 string bullet = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buffer);
//why are you adding the "." bullet back with BODY = BODY + "." ?

Create a StringBuilder and use the Append Method()

StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder(); //add a capacity if you know the size you want like this for example StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder(200); 
messageBuilder.Append("\t\u2022\t"); 
messageBuilder.Append("Text1\r\n");

follow the pattern with what you need.
Thanks
```

Comment: Thanks, Append works fine, but still - I have the same problem - my BULLETS are messed up "â€¢" - this is what I am getting when I append the "•" symbol to the file.

Comment: What do you mean that's what you are getting.. are you hard coding the symbol or using unicode "\u2022"

Comment: can you please pase in the exact code that you are using.. I will try it on my end to see if I am seeing / getting the same results ok